# 3 - 6 months investments in Canada?

Tags: canada, investing

What are some best instruments in Canadian market for 3 - 6 months investments? I have no knowledge of options/derivatives etc, so mainly looking for other alternatives here.

EDIT: On a scale of 1 - 10, if I divide my capital in 2 parts, for one part, risk is high (~7), other part, risk is low (~3)

Only 3 - 6 months because I cannot block money for more than that time. I bought a condo and all my liquid cash is now gone.

EDIT # 2: from the responses, I udnerstand, 3 - 6 months is too short. If I increase the horizon to 18 - 24 months, how do my options change?

Comment: What kind of investments?  Where on the spectrum are you between either (a) preserving your capital, or (b) taking wild-ass risks where you might lose it all?  And **why** is your time horizon only 3-6 months?

Comment: Please see EDIT.

Comment: upping the the timeframe to almost two years does not change the advice much.  +1 for MrChrister

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a saver, not an investor.  Your time period is simply too short.  You are stuck putting your money into less productive, but safe savings accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have insider information (ILLEGAL!!!) don't go high risk over this time frame.  It makes about as much sense as betting on the horses.

Stick it in a 3 or 6 month GIC at the pathetic rates the banks are giving.